# Help identifying small low-flying aircraft over western US?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Have spotted this aircraft flying over the western U.S. more than once this July: a couple of times in early July north of Spokane, WA, and today over the Silicon Valley area. All times it was flying very low, but was relatively quiet for how close to the ground it was. It appears to have two propellers on each wing and is a plain gray, which makes me think it may be military. My searches for military aircraft that fit this description have come up blank though. Any help with identification is appreciated!

Blurry photo below is the best I was able to get.

[image: Image of aircraft]

Comment: First time I've ever heard a C-130 described as *quiet*!  Usually their distinctively *loud* sound is one of the main give-aways!  Maybe that's somehow unique to when the pass over at *higher* altitude-- you get that all-pervasive gently throbbing roar-- PS re "First time I've ever heard a C-130 described as *quiet*!"-- *or small*!!

Comment: That's why I initially dismissed considering it a C-130: it seemed too quiet and too small, even though the shape looked similar!

Comment: @quietflyer I expect from their description of it as "small" that it was in fact higher up than OP thought it was.

Comment: Well, it wasn't a toy (radio-controlled, perhaps electric) model of a C-130 was it?  Perhaps in "giant scale" so that it looked like a real a/c?  (Just kidding-- mostly!)  PS @Chris-RegenerateResponse -- yes just as w/ birds, size of flying a/c can be deceptively hard to judge of altitude is not known, and vice versa, unless the thing in question has already been definitively identified--

Comment: Probably will conclude that I misjudged the altitude, thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: You may wish to edit your title - that is a **HUGE** aircraft!!!

Comment: The odds that you saw the *same* aircraft in both locations are extremely remote. You probably saw multiple instances of the same type.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is a Lockheed C-130 (Hercules), generally used by the military. The civilian variant is an [L-100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_L-100_Hercules) Hercules.

Also, the C-130 is not so small (per your question).  It's max takeoff weight is similar to a B737 and it has a longer wing span.

[image]

[Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_C-130_Hercules)

Comment: Hercs are still relatively small, especially on the scale of transport aircraft. For comparison: https://external-preview.redd.it/XNtf3O7nAPc8TYkk_IpXIXqBTY45TKh-y3nLnOST-Nc.jpg?width=1200&height=628.272251309&auto=webp&s=029a6f9535e28eab460f6077ee44c40992f0a5d3

Answer (score 12):

I believe this is an HC-130J Combat King II based on the wing tanks and paint scheme, from the 129th Rescue Wing, which is based out of  Moffett Federal Airfield, California, based on where you reported seeing it (the Silicon Valley).

https://www.af.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/104468/hc-130j-combat-king-ii/
https://www.dvidshub.net/feature/hc130jfeaturepage

Comment: I wouldn't put too much stock into a paint scheme, and the wing tanks can be fitted to any (all?) variants, used for transport/ferrying, and more.